# Where does the paragraph end in Genesis 37:2

Tags: genesis, literary-structure, nasb

I'm converting [this link](http://www.newcreationstudies.org/Bible) into HTML, so when I came across Genesis 37:2, I got stumped because I don't see where there might be a closing `</p>` tag.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, really: the link is (I guess) leading to a 4.5Mb HTML file. My suggestion would be to compare the markup with the [Biblegateway NASB for Genesis 37](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=gen+37&version=NASB) and make sense of it that way. As it stands, I'm not sure this is on topic for BH.SE.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about HTML markup, not about biblical interpretation.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is a html question! Genesis is built up by the '[toledot](http://www.lanz.li/joom/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=52&Itemid=1)' form. With Gen. 37:2 starts the toledot of Jacob. So, I think Gen 37:1 belongs to the toledot of Esau, Gen. 36. I'm studying the life and significance of Esau in Scripture and I discovered that Gen. 36 tells the history of the natural human (in contrast to the spiritual human). The end of Gen. 36 speaks about the chiefs of Edomite, and this is the time of 'the Millennium'. In the Millennium, Jacob owns the promised land, so Gen 37:1 says: Jacob dwelt in the land of *his father's sojournings*, in the land of Canaan. But in the time of Jacob, he didn't posses Canaan! Not only his father Isaac, but he also. So, I conclude that this verse also sign for the Messianic period of the Millennium.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly how this answers where the paragraph should be divided? Also, editing a link into your answer such as [this reference to a "toledot" structure in Genesis](http://www.lanz.li/joom/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=52&Itemid=1) would be helpful.

Comment: I agree with Cohen_the_Librarian: it remains unclear to me how your (valiant attempt at an) answer addresses OP's concern. The *toledot* structural marker is too broad to be of help here. The problem is one of NASB editorial choices about paragraph boundaries and HTML markup ... really.